# Solid background with portion of it is gradient light effect

Tags: html, css, background, tailwind-css, gradient

How can I do this background like in tailwind? Is it possible either using vanilla CSS or tailwind CSS?

[image: Tailwind Background]

I did not try yet, I am still searching and seeking the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Tailwind site uses an image with the "gradient light" and a transparent background to achieve this effect.

HTML:

[image: Tailwind site HTML]

Background image:

[image: Background image]